# How to change font inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery tablesorter api to display table data now i want to change the text font inside table. Please let me know if anybody has any idea how to achieve it.

Thanks,
Sharad

Comment: Please share what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `themes/blue/style.css` or `themes/green/style.css` and change the font-family to the font you'd like.